# Net log and QSO submission question

Tags: logging, net

New ham here. Is it common practice and acceptable to submit net logs as QSOs to QRZ, eQSL, LoTW, etc?

One person told me they log other's callsigns checking in to a net they're participating in and submit them as QSOs.

Another person told me they only log and submit only the net control operator as a QSO.

Which is correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you called them, and they called you, that's a QSO. There are some nets arranged specifically to facilitate working a bunch of different people (like WAS nets).

If you didn't address a transmission specifically to them, or they didn't address a transmission specifically to you, that's no QSO and I wouldn't consider it loggable.

Comment: That's what I figured as well. Logging everyone checking in just sounded....off.

Comment: @Mac net control's job is to log everyone checking in, but for a somewhat different reason :)

Answer (score 1):

Good Morning, all,
There was a time when I was a bit fanatical about logging and confirming a QSO with a QSL. In the 1970s I would use a tape recorder and then log all the mobile contacts once arrived at a destination. Today, I log for personal use, listing all stations that check into a net, thinking if I have to assume net control, I would have a fairly complete list of checkins.  However, with the advent of electronic logs that automatically enter your contacts in the online logs such as LoTW, QRZ, HamCall, HamQTH, and Club Log I have noticed some today are like I was in the 70s, and they challenge the log. I seldom file RST, either sent or received when logging net contacts.  But it still seems to be an issue for some.  I receive requests to correct my log from time to time. I typically write the station back and provide the explanation above.  But it is getting more complicated. Again, I log for my personal use.